# ASP.NET MVC - how to modify requested URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, filtering

The baidu spider seems to be adding `¤` to end of some crawled urls (it seems that it happens with urls containing single unicode character as the last character)

The baidu-requested url looks like this:

`site.com/abc/ä¤`

while

`site.com/abc/ä` is the valid url and as linked from many places on my site.

The internal problem is that a different route is matched for this kind of url and an unhandled exception occurs.

I would not like to lose baidu because of too many 500 errors on the site.

I would like to change the requested URL to a different URL by removing the added character before any ASP.NET MVC processing of the request starts.

**Can I write a request filter/http module or something similar in ASP.NET MVC to remove the trailing '¤' from the urls?** I would not like to alter my routes to counter-hack this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the "fix it in the Route" answer, but here's an alternative (sorry it's in VB)

```
Public Class BaseController : Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    Protected Overrides Function CreateActionInvoker() As System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker
            If HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.EndsWith("¤") Then
                Dim redir As String = Replace(HttpContext.Request.RawUrl, "¤", "")
                Response.Redirect(redir)
            End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

then inherit ALL of your controllers from the BaseController

Note: string.replace is not the "best" way if the trailing character is valid in a normal URL, you'll want to trim it off some other way.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure, but maybe adding a route like "{controller}/{action}/{id}¤", with the caracter there on the end

this route should come before the one you're currently using

Comment: As I have stated in my question, I would like to find a way how to fix this without modifying my routes

Comment: well, filters are applied after the routes, so the best place to do this is in the routes. filtering this before the controller would be much worse